# Why can i still make request while the server is disconnected?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio.

I log in my server, open a "new request" window and write a query that select ALL the element of a table.

SQL Server then display a table with the content queried.

However, as this request work when i'm connected, which is perfectly logic, i don't understand why this request still work when i disconnect from the server.

Is it a normal behavior ? When i disconnect from a server it's specifically to not execute a query by accident.

Comment: most likely your tool automatically reconnects when it got disconnected. How do you know that you got disconnected?

Comment: When you say disconnect, do you mean on your server connection on the left plane or on the current query you are on? Because a query can be open with a seperate connection to a database than from your left databases pane

Comment: @ikrabbe know it because i pressed the disconnected button, so i'm 100% sure i'm not connected to any server since the list on the left part of sql server management is empty.

Comment: @Hano Johannes Rossouw I mean the server connection on the left plane.

Comment: Thats what i mean, on your left it can be empty because that list's connection has been disconnected but the queries that are open run in a separate window and use a seperate connection

Comment: right click on your query window, go to connection and select disconnect then the query will not be able to run

Comment: I thought the query windows would use the current connection ?

That explains much, you guys should write as answer so i can accept it.

Comment: They do when you open them on the current database , but they use a different connection, so if you close your conneciton on the left your query still has its own connection open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say disconnect, do you mean on your server connection on the left plane or on the current query you are on? Because a query can be open with a seperate connection to a database than from your left databases pane. It can be empty because that list's connection has been disconnected but the queries that are open run in a separate window and use a seperate connection –

Right click on your query window, go to connection and select disconnect then the query will not be able to run

When you open a query on the current database they will use the connection details, but they use a seperate connection to the database, so if you close your conneciton on the left databases pane. your query still has its own connection open

Answer (score -1):

Most probably the query result is cashed for better performance. That is why for the next select it doesn't use the connection, just the cashed result. You can even add the where condition and it will work.

Comment: That's not the case, i tried to insert some elements, which worked.

Then i did another select query while connected and it showed me the new inserted elements.

Comment: Yes, just figured out the separate disconnect for the right pane.